# Postgresql date comparison with two timestamps without timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an error while trying to compare datetimes with `rails` and `postgresql`

Now, I created the table using this simple schema:

```
def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string     :name
      t.datetime   :start_time
    end
end
```

I try then to get events in the future using this scope:

```
scope :active_events, ->(id) { includes(:event).where(:foursquare_id => id).where('events.start_time => now()::timestamp') }
```

That translate in postgresql as :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "venues"."id") 
FROM "venues" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "events" ON "events"."venue_id" = "venues"."id" 
WHERE "venues"."foursquare_id" = '4ada1e5ff964a5209f1e21e3' 
  AND (events.start_time => now()::timestamp)
```

Now I have this error that shows up then :

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone => timestamp without time zone
LINE 1: ...'4ada1e5ff964a5209f1e21e3' AND (events.start_time => now()::...
```

and I'm really not sure to understand this. Normally they are of the same data type I assume they would be able to compare but it doesn't seem to be the case.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you're looking for is `>=`, `=>` is usually used with [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html).

Comment: Oh wow, what a careless mistake! Thanks for showing it to me :-)